# Complex Analysis Exam Question - Conformal Mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been trying to solve this problem from the past paper exam of my complex analysis class. I am just following the solution procedure introduced in class, and couldn't find the line in the $f(z)$ that corresponds to $x+y=1$ .

Problem:

> Suppose the region $D$ is the region surrounded by $x=0$, $y=0$, and $x+y=1$. If $w = f(z) = z + z^2$, illustrate the mapping of the region $D$ in $f(z)$.

PS: [What I have tried. Also, he solution is given in the green box.](https://imgur.com/gallery/7brN17O)